# datediff is always 1 number less than I need

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following which seems to work perfectly, except that it's always 1 less than the count I need:

```
DECLARE @start_day DATETIME;
DECLARE @end_day DATETIME;
DECLARE @start_time DATETIME;
DECLARE @end_time DATETIME;

SET @start_day = '2013-06-03';
SET @end_day = '2013-06-07';

PRINT   DATEDIFF(d, @start_day, @end_day)
      - DATEDIFF(wk, @start_day, @end_day) * 2
      - CASE 
            WHEN DATEPART(dw, @start_day) != 7 AND DATEPART(dw, @end_day) = 7 THEN 1 
            WHEN DATEPART(dw, @start_day) = 7 AND DATEPART(dw, @end_day) != 7 THEN -1 
            ELSE 0
        END
```

I should be getting

```
`5` for `2013-06-03` to `2013-06-07` but it's giving me `4`.
`5` for `2013-06-03` to `2013-06-08` but it's giving me `4`.
`5` for `2013-06-03` to `2013-06-09` but it's giving me `4`.
`6` for `2013-06-03` to `2013-06-10` but it's giving me `5`.
```

So my question is:

How do I get:

```
`2013-06-03` to `2013-06-07` to equal 5
`2013-06-03` to `2013-06-08` to equal 5
`2013-06-03` to `2013-06-09` to equal 5
`2013-06-03` to `2013-06-10` to equal 6
```

---

**Please note, adding +1 to the end does not solve the problem!!!**

Comment: That doesn't work.  If I do that, it will add 1 for weekends too, which it shouldn't do.

Comment: That's how `DATEDIFF` is supposed to work. The difference between `2013-6-18` and `2013-6-18` should surely be `0`. So the difference between `2013-6-18` and '2013-6-19` will be `1`... etc etc

Comment: My second comment isn't in response to your first comment...

Comment: Updated my question with 4 examples at the bottom instead of the original 1 example.

Comment: Updated end of question again to clarify the actual question being asked.

Comment: So basically you are saying you want datediff in days which are mondays, tuesdays, wednesdays, thursdays and fridays but not saturdays nor sundays?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen, yes.

Comment: It's really not clear want you want to achieve. Could you please explain it in english.

Comment: @Serge, I simply want to count the days between 2 dates including the start date, and excluding saturday and sunday.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović, yes the solution in that link worked perfectly!  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Create table foo (
StartDate datetime not null,
EndDate datetime not null
)

insert into foo (StartDate, EndDate) values (N'2013-06-03', N'2013-06-07'),
(N'2013-06-03', N'2013-06-08'),
(N'2013-06-03', N'2013-06-09'),
(N'2013-06-03', N'2013-06-10')

SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(d, StartDate, EndDate)
    + CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, StartDate) <= 5 THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
        END
    - DATEDIFF(wk, StartDate, EndDate) * 2
    - CASE 
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, StartDate) != 7 AND DATEPART(dw, EndDate) = 7 THEN 1 
        WHEN DATEPART(dw, StartDate) = 7 AND DATEPART(dw, EndDate) != 7 THEN -1 
        ELSE 0
    END 
FROM foo
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e6f4/3)

Comment: This gives me a `2` if `start = 2013-06-01` and `end = 2013-06-03`.  It should give me `1`.

Comment: What should it give you for `start = 2013-06-01` and `end = 2013-06-01`

Comment: `start = 2013-06-01` and `end = 2013-06-01` should be `0` as it's not a monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, or friday.

Comment: Wasn't thinking about the week-based `DATEDIFF` when I wrote mine obviously! Mine does work for 'end-date precedes start-date` though :) (If you want that)

Comment: Ok - bad date! `start = 2013-06-18` and `end = 2013-06-18`

Comment: All I want is to simply count days given 2 dates, excluding saturday and sunday + 1 for the start date.

Comment: For `start = 2013-06-18` and `end = 2013-06-18`, I need it to give me a `1`.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen, still not working right.  yes the `2013-06-03` to `2013-06-07` is giving back `5`, but `2013-06-07` to `2013-06-08` should be giving a `1`  Your script is giving a `0`.

Comment: What is your sql server considering the first day of week? SELECT @@DATEFIRST

Comment: @JanneMatikainen, got it working, please see duplicate link in comments below my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to replicate Excel's [NETWORKDAYS](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/networkdays-HP005209190.aspx) then I wrote this ages ago...

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnNetworkDays]
(
    @date1 SMALLDATETIME,
    @date2 SMALLDATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret INT,
            @dt1 INT,
            @dt2 INT,
            @dt3 INT,
            @neg INT,
            @wks INT,
            @dyo INT,
            @wkd INT,
            @take INT
    --Midnightise the dates
    SELECT @date1 = DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@date1)), @date2 = DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0,@date2))
    --Get integers to make the calcs easier
    SELECT @dt1 = CONVERT(INT,@date1),@dt2 = CONVERT(INT,@date2)

    IF @dt1 > @dt2
        BEGIN
        SET @neg = -1
        SET @dt3 = @dt1
        SET @dt1 = @dt2
        SET @dt2 = @dt3
        END
    ELSE
        SET @neg = 1

    SET @ret = @dt2 - @dt1 + 1
    SET @wks = FLOOR(@ret / 7)
    SET @dyo = @ret % 7
    SET @wkd = @dt1 % 7

    SELECT @take=CASE @wkd
        WHEN 0 THEN CASE WHEN @dyo = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        WHEN 6 THEN CASE WHEN @dyo = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ELSE CASE WHEN @dyo = (6 - @wkd) THEN 1 ELSE CASE WHEN @dyo > (6 - @wkd) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END END
    END 

    SELECT @ret =  @neg * (@ret - @wks * 2 - @take) 

    RETURN @ret
END
```

Probably over-complicated but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use a COUNT with a tally table.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.tTally
WHERE n BETWEEN DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @from) AND DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @to)
AND DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(dd, n, 0)) NOT IN (7, 1)
```

[tally table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)